# Is tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer a vanilla GradientDescent?

Tags: tensorflow

Is `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` a vanilla gradient descent? i.e. not SGD, so it is equivalent to a gradient update implemented in numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the vanilla gradient descent. You can't say it is not SGD. Because it depends on your number of examples you consider when training a single epoch.

Which means if you use only a mini-batch (ideally one single instance, but mini-batch is also fine) of data for a single epoch, We call it SGD.

Yes functionally it should be equivalent to `numpy` implementation.